# Laptop fan operates for a long time

Tags: overheating

My laptop Dell inspiron 15R 3521 heats a lot when I installed ubuntu along with windows 7. How to avoid this ??? (I checked all the drivers but they are all propriety drivers. I have a shared VGA. 4GB ram...thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is the ubuntu version you installed? If it is a prior version to 13.04, you can install jupitor to solve your issue somewhat. Though this won't help you much, its worth trying.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pyjupiter
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Overheat problem is very common among ubuntu users and many people use different solutions such as turning off dedicated graphics cards if hybrid graphics is used etc. Since you have only share VGA, that method is not applicable.